# How to listen to firebase onBackgroundMessage function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, background, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open modal when message will be received and I have done it successfully on foreground messages but on background messages I couldn't make it work. The problem is that I have done it successfully on clicking button but can't make it to open automatically. JavaScript `"focus"` and `"visibilitychange"` listeners make it re-render myriad times. Also, I can't export `onBackgroundMessage` function from my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` like `onMessageListener` in foreground. here is the code of firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js");


const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


const openDatabase = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open('qapp-firebase-messages', 1);

    request.onerror = () => {
      console.error('Error opening IndexedDB database.');
      reject(request.error);
    };

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      resolve(request.result);
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('messages')) {
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('messages', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
      }
    };
  });
};


const storeMessage = async (messageData) => {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('messages', 'readwrite');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('messages');
  const request = objectStore.put(messageData);
  transaction.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('Error storing message in IndexedDB:', error);
  };
};


function retrieveMessages() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const request = indexedDB.open('qapp-firebase-messages', 1);
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      const tx = db.transaction('messages', 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore('messages');
      const messages = [];
      store.openCursor().onsuccess = async function (event) {
        const cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          const copy = { ...cursor.value }
          messages.push(copy);
          // await cursor.delete();
          cursor.continue();
        } else {
          resolve(messages);
        }
      };
    };
  });
}

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("backgroundmessages recieved")
  console.log(payload.data)
  storeMessage(payload.data);
});
```

`console.log` works and it logs respectively. It also stores messages in indexedDB correctly, but I don't know how to communicate this file with my app because this file is in the public folder respectively.